# Read another apps version and build number on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to get other apps version and build number in iOS (using apples private API). The app will not be on the store so it is not a problem to use private api if needed. I have found some solutions using LSWorkspace and LSApplicationProxy but since iOS 11 they do not seem to work. I have bundle identifiers of the apps that I want to get the data about. Is that possible, has anyone found a way for reading installed apps info on iOS 11?

Comment: You can legally get info about installed apps with MDM - Mobile Device Management. You will need enterprise account with enabled MDM. Peoples will need just install yours configuration profile with MDM.

Comment: @Cy-4AH thanks for the reply. Any other ways because other apps could not be edited at the moment